# 環境変数をawk内で使う方法

Tags: linux, shellscript, zsh

環境変数Nに数字が入っていたとして、

```
awk "NR>N"
```

のように awk のスクリプト内で変数の値を使いたいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

awk の `-v` オプションを使ってください。

```
awk -v N="$N" 'NR>N'
```

### 理由

他に考えられる方法として、シェルの変数展開を使う方法もあります。

```
awk "NR>$N"
```

しかしこの方法には 2 つ欠点があります。

1. 一般には可読性が落ちます。awk スクリプトを書く際は内部での無駄なエスケープを避けるため、全体をシングルクォートで囲いたくなることがあります。その上でこの方法を使おうとするとシングルクォートとダブルクォートが入り乱れ可読性が落ちてしまいます。
2. 変数の中身が awk スクリプトとして解釈されてしまう可能性が排除されます。シェルによる展開を使うと変数の中身を使った文字列がそのまま awk の引数として渡されるため、シェルの変数の中に awk スクリプトとして解釈可能なものが入っていればそれが awk によって解釈されてしまいます。`-v` を使う方法ではそうなりません。

2 の例：

```
$ CMD='; print "piyopiyo"'
$ awk "BEGIN { print $CMD }"

piyopiyo
$ awk -v CMD="$CMD" 'BEGIN { print CMD }'
; print "piyopiyo"
```

Comment: 丁寧な理由までありがとうございます。もう一つ質問してもいいでしょうか？awk内で変数二つ扱う場合、例えば NとM。この場合はどのように記述したらいいのでしょうか。ググってみたら -v N=$N M=$Mとか-v N=$N -v M=$Mなどあるのですが、どれが良いのでしょうか？

Comment: man をご覧ください。たとえば POSIX の仕様 https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html には "Multiple occurrences of this option can be specified." と書かれており、`-v N="$N" -v M="$M"` 形式が許されていることが分かります。